# PyQT5, Qlabel over QProgessbar results in sometimes wrong displayed progress

Tags: python, pyqt5

[image: screenshot]

Hi, in the attached picture you can see how the QLabels with the QProgressbar looks like. In the first line you can see two states of the progressbar, they are displayed correctly.
When the pump (the progressbar shows how full the zylinder is, which temperature it has and what the flow rate is) is working, it happens sometimes that the the progressbar does not refresh correctly. It then basically looks like the first picture in the second row. I found out that the boarders seem to be the same as the boarders of the labels. They are made in QTDesigner.
Since the bar looks correct when it is either full or empty, I think there might be something wrong with PyQT.

I am having a main window and a QThread. The QThread gets the data from a hardware and sends it via a signal to the mainwindow. I tried first to use a QThread with a while true loop and a sleep at the end of the run()-function and thought maybe this blocks the main thread and rewrote it with a Qtimer based approach, but the behaviour is the same.

Edit: Here is a video of the problem: https://youtu.be/ZVLS2dgzRxc

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal, QTimer
import Communication
from Communication import prepare_senddata
from Communication import translate_dict
from time import sleep


class DirectControl(QThread):
    signal_data_dict = pyqtSignal(dict)

    def __init__(self):
        QThread.__init__(self)
        self.counter_on = 0

    def run(self):
        senddata = prepare_senddata(templow=self.templow, temphigh=self.temphigh,
                                pressure0=self.pressure, pressure1=self.pressure, flow0=self.flow0,
                                flow1=self.flow1, valves=self.valves)
        getdata = Communication.SPI.sendget(senddata)
        data_dict = translate_dict(getdata, senddata)
        self.signal_data_dict.emit(data_dict)

    def stop(self):
        self.counter_on = 0
        self.wait()
        senddata = prepare_senddata()
        Communication.SPI.sendget(senddata)

    def start_timer(self):
        if self.counter_on == 1:
            QTimer.singleShot(300, self.start_timer)
            self.start()

    def start_thread(self):
        self.counter_on = 1
        self.start_timer()

class DirectControlWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_DirectControlWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.DirectControlThread = DirectControl()
        self.DirectControlThread.signal_data_dict.connect(self.refreshdata)

    def close_clicked(self):
        self.DirectControlThread.stop()
        self.close()

    def refreshdata(self, data_dict):
        self.pCold.setValue(int(data_dict['vol_cold']))
        self.lVCold.setText(str(data_dict['vol_cold']) + 'ml')
        self.lTCold.setText(str(data_dict['temp_cold']) + '°C')
        self.lColdFlow.setText(str(data_dict['flow1']) + 'ml/s')
```

complete example:

```
    import sys, time
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class Thread(QtCore.QThread):
    data = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self):
        super(Thread, self).__init__()
        self.up = True
        self.i = 0

    def run(self):
        while True:
            if self.up:
                self.data.emit(int(self.i))
                self.i += 1
                if self.i == 100:
                    self.up = False
            else:
                self.data.emit(int(self.i))
                self.i -= 1
                if self.i == 0:
                    self.up = True
            time.sleep(0.1)


class Ui_DirectControlWindow(object):

    def setupUi(self, DirectControlWindow):
        DirectControlWindow.setObjectName("DirectControlWindow")
        DirectControlWindow.resize(800, 480)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(DirectControlWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pCold = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(self.centralwidget)
        self.pCold.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 200, 61, 131))
        self.pCold.setStyleSheet("QProgressBar {"
                         "border: 1px solid black;"
                         "text-align: top;"
                         "padding: 1px;"
                         "border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;"
                         "border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;"
                         "width: 15px;"
                         "background-color: rgb(195, 203, 202);"
                         "}"
                         "QProgressBar::chunk {"
                         "background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);"
                         "border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;"
                         "border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;"
                         "border: 1px solid black;"
                         "}")
        self.pCold.setMaximum(100)
        self.pCold.setProperty("value", 0)
        self.pCold.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeading|QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.pCold.setTextVisible(False)
        self.pCold.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
        self.pCold.setInvertedAppearance(True)
        self.pCold.setTextDirection(QtWidgets.QProgressBar.TopToBottom)
        self.pCold.setFormat("%p%")
        self.pCold.setObjectName("pCold")
        self.lTCold = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.lTCold.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 230, 61, 16))
        self.lTCold.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.lTCold.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.lTCold.setObjectName("lTCold")
        self.lVCold = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.lVCold.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 260, 61, 16))
        self.lVCold.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.lVCold.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.lVCold.setObjectName("lVCold")
        self.pCold.raise_()
        self.lTCold.raise_()
        self.lVCold.raise_()
        DirectControlWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        DirectControlWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("DirectControlWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.lTCold.setText(_translate("DirectControlWindow", "20°C"))
        self.lVCold.setText(_translate("DirectControlWindow", "120ml"))
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(DirectControlWindow)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_DirectControlWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.ErrorWindow = Ui_DirectControlWindow()
        self.Thread = Thread()
        self.Thread.data.connect(self.signal_accept)
        self.Thread.start()

    def signal_accept(self, msg):
        self.pCold.setValue(int(msg))
        self.lTCold.setText(str(msg) + 'num')
        self.lVCold.setText(str(msg) + 'ml')


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec()
```

Comment: Are you on macOS? Which version? And which Qt version (`QtCore.QT_VERSION_STR`)?

Comment: Hi, I am on windows and on Linux (Rasperry Pi with Raspberry OS (Debain 11) ). Same behaviour on both. Version is 5.15.2. I moved the labels off the progress bar and the effects went away, even though the steps are still somehow coarse.

Comment: Unfortunately, your code is missing too many aspects to be able to properly understand where the problem is. The only way to help you is to provide a [mre] that is self-contained and allows us to test it even without the need of external libraries or components that we couldn't replicate.

Comment: Here is a complete example (I found out it has something to do with the stylesheet, because the effect vanishes when I leave it out. But I did not found a soltion to make it blue with rounded corners). I will edit first post.